# Trying to access another class in member function - CPP

Tags: c++

I have a team class made up of an array of players from a separate player class I made. Im trying to create a member function 'getRoster()' which prints out the names of the players on the team but am getting an error that my array of players is undefined. Im pretty new to classes so if I explained something poorly please let me know and I can try and clarify.

player.h :

```
class Player 
{
    private:
        string name;
        string team;
        int position; 

    public:
        Player();
        Player(string newName, string newTeam, int newPosition, int newAttributes[]);
        string getName();
        void setName(string newName);
        string getTeam();
        void setTeam(string newTeam);
        int getPosition();
        void setPosition(int newPosition);
        int getAttribute(int index); //index of the attribute you want to return
        bool setAttribute(int index, int newAttribute);
};
```

team.h :

```
class Team
{
private:
    string teamName;
    static const int rosterSize = 5;
    Player roster[5];

public:
    Team();
    Team(string team, int rosterSize, Player newRoster[]);
    string getTeamName();
    void setTeamName(string newTeam);
    int getRosterSize();
    void getRoster();
    bool setRoster(int index, Player players[]);
};
```

team.cpp part I am having issues with :

```
Team::Team(string team, int rosterSize, Player newRoster[])
{
team = team;

rosterSize = rosterSize;

for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    roster[i] = newRoster[i];
}
}

void getRoster()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) 
    {
        cout << roster[i].getName() << endl;
    }
}
```

the roster[I] part is getting an undefined error.

here is the error output :
{

```
"resource": "/Users/henrydyer/Documents/csci1300/Project 3/team.cpp",
    "owner": "C/C++",
    "code": "20",
    "severity": 8,
    "message": "identifier \"roster\" is undefined",
    "source": "C/C++",
    "startLineNumber": 64,
    "startColumn": 17,
    "endLineNumber": 64,
    "endColumn": 23
}
```

Thanks

Comment: If you get build errors, then please [edit] your question to copy-paste the full and complete error output.

Comment: On another note, the assignment `team = team` will not do what you probably think it does. It assign to the local argument variable `team`, not the member variable of the same name. That's why the next assignment to `rosterSize` works, as you can't assign to the constant member variable.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I added in the error message, hope that helps

Comment: How do you define the `getRoster` function? Is the definition (implementation) really in the `Team` class?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I defined 'void getRoster()' in the public specifier of the team class if that's what your asking

Comment: Yes but when you *implement* the function (in the `team.cpp` source file), in which class (if any) is it then?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude that solved it , don't know how I couldn't catch that thanks